# Remove horizontal space incurred by \' in tabbing

Tags: tabbing

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabbing}
FOO\=\kill
FOO\>BAR\\  
\>O\'BAR\\  
\end{tabbing}
\end{document}
```

The output is

[image: output after compiling with latex]

How to remove the space after "O" in the second line, moving this "O" to the right, i.e., to get

```
FOOBAR
  OBAR
```

?

This question is specific to `tabbing` (we all know how to achieve this result in other environments, say, `tabular`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

30 years of tex use and first time I have ever set this parameter:-)

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\setlength\tabbingsep{0pt}
\begin{tabbing}
FOO\=\kill
FOO\>BAR\\  
\>O\'BAR\\  
\end{tabbing}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @user49915 it is fairly fully documented in the latex book (which is where I just looked) but I think I have only used the tabbing environment a couple of times, it is fairly useless really, I think.

Comment: @user49915 yes...